# Tag wiki edits are missing in the activity profile tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki, recent-activity

It appears that tag wiki edits are again misreported in the activity tab of user profiles.

I first noticed this on [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/). Consider for example the [`france` tag wiki](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/458/revisions): [Gagravarr](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/26/gagravarr?tab=activity)'s creation and edits don't appear in his activity, while [I'm credited](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/277/gilles?tab=activity) for creating it even though I merely edited it. On [`uk`](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/412/revisions), neither of us is credited.

This isn't limited to Travel or to suggested edits. My latest edit to [`wildcards` on Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/16020/revisions) doesn't appear in my [activity](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles?tab=activity).

While I'm at it, tag wiki creations seem to be reported at the wrong date: for example, on [travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/277/gilles?tab=activity), I'm credited for creating the `uk` excerpt on June 24, but that's actually the date the tag was created, I only created the excerpt on July 8.

[image: activity screenshot]

Comment: OT:  Capture app?

Comment: @Won't If you meant which capture app: as it says in the watermark, [Explain and Send Screenshots](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mdddabjhelpilpnpgondfmehhcplpiin), which is pretty convenient. If you mean the watermark is ugly: I agree, I've just been too lazy to do anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed at some point: all the examples of tag wiki activity that I mention in my bug reports now appear in the correct user's history at the correct date.