# Are tag wiki edits supposed to show up in user activity before they're approved?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, recent-activity, activity-summary

I'm 99% sure I actually clicked "Save Edits" on a proposed tag wiki for "customcomponents" a couple days ago. The edit is not showing up in my activity on SO, though - so maybe I didn't?  So am I crazy, or do proposed edits not show up?

I found [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59289/editing-a-tag-wiki-should-show-in-your-activity-log) that suggests that this was added at some point as a feature.  I also found [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98380/tag-wiki-edits-are-missing-in-the-activity-profile-tab), from not that long ago, suggesting this is broken - but at least there are tag-wiki edits showing in the screenshot.

My activity has nothing at the moment, and I'm wondering if that's because the activity "doesn't count" until it's reviewed and/or approved.

Is this supposed to work for *proposed* edits, or only accepted ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proposed edits are shown [in your activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3782/mcw0933?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_revisions) once they are approved; in that case, you would notice a +2 entry in your [reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3782/mcw0933?tab=reputation#reppage_1-repview_post), too.

Before they are approved, they are not shown in any place. You would need to remember which tag wiki you edited, visit the tag info page, and check to see if the message "Thanks for your edit!" is displayed at the top.

Comment: Got it.  So if I want to see my submission before it's approved... I'm SOL?

Comment: You need to remember which tag wiki you edited, visit the tag info page, and check if you see the message "Thanks for your edit!" at the top.