# I created 50 tag wikis before my second post on Stack Overflow?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, tag-wiki, activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Activity log entry before registration date](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110741/activity-log-entry-before-registration-date)

I looked at the [last page of my activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500584/agf?tab=activity&sort=all&page=363) today, and discovered it is full of

> created TAGNAME description
>
> created TAGNAME excerpt

entries. So are the two pages before it.

It seems that for every tag wiki I edited, I am credited with creating that excerpt or description on the date it was originally created.

[image: Screenshot]

For example, I joined SO in December 2010, and the hover text in the above screenshot clearly shows I created the [java](/questions/tagged/java) wiki excerpt months earlier.

Comment: So, funny story: I accidentally click on the "java" tag link in your question, and the first question I saw was [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152499/pls-help-me-in-doing-java-code-for-this-how-to-start).

Comment: What question? I don't see any question :P

Comment: I have the same on my page, but only for the [tag:ant] tag wiki excerpt.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann When did you edit that? All my edits were made in the last couple of days.

Comment: On June 18th 2011 - but it is still the latest excerpt edit up to day. Maybe there got a `<` mixed with `>` or something similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have been battling the activity stream tag wiki stuff for a while now, for example: [Tag wiki edits are missing in the activity profile tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98380/tag-wiki-edits-are-missing-in-the-activity-profile-tab)

Initially when I designed tag wikis "community user" created the wiki blank and then the end user "revised" the blank wiki. Some people found this confusing so we changed it so the initial revision is a "proper" creation revision however the post is owned by community.

Trouble is this design makes querying for activity very very annoying. We cache an entry in our Posts table for `LastEditorUserId`, however have no cached entry for `FirstEditorUserId`.

There was a bug there that used `LastEditorUserId` as though it was `FirstEditorUserId`.

I amended the query to properly join into `PostHistory` to figure out the proper timeline.

Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: to be deployed post 2012.5.1.2410

Comment: In time for the bounty, eh? :)

Comment: Thanks! Could you mark http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110741/activity-log-entry-before-registration-date `status-completed` and close one of these as a dupe of the other?