# Tag edits don't appear in the combined activity log

Tags: bug, tags, suggested-edits, profile-page, tag-wiki

Recently I edited many tag wikis, but they didn't appear in my combined activity log (URL: `https://stackexchange.com/users/<your-se-id>?tab=activity`).

This bug report is *not* a dupe of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98380/tag-wiki-edits-are-missing-in-the-activity-profile-tab), and many similar ones: these are about the activity log in the *individual sites*, while this report is about the combined activity log (as also the URL shows).

My site activity shows them correctly.

Comment: [Related problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300353/259412)

Comment: Just so you know, `me` works as a `<your-se-id>` magic "number".

Comment: @wizzwizz4 afaik, its "current" for the users/ path.

Comment: @Braiam You are correct. I was thinking of search.