# Display error in Accounts tab in Profile page

Tags: bug, profile-page, user-accounts, network-profile

This is a screenshot of my profile:

[image]

What has led to this error in [my network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/10466389/truth-seek?tab=accounts)? Can I do something to correct this?

Comment: As per [your profile](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/148764/phyenthusiast), you have asked 20 questions in Physics.

Comment: Did you have your account merged or something before?

Comment: [Related problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300351/259412)

Comment: @Elias Yeah I think I did something like that.